# Add additional rows conditioned on a column values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with `item`, `number_of_repeats` (row repetition times), `row_vale_string` (row value in the result table, here separated by commas).

I have another dataframe in which all `items` are listed in mixed up order. I would like to

a) ADD number of rows = `total_repeats`;

b) for each row, keep `item` as is

c) add `row_value` from the `row_value_string`.

I am looking for `dplyr` solution for this.

```
Item    total_repeats   row_value_string 
101     4               1,2,3,4 
102     2               1,2 
103     4               1,2,3,4 
104     1               1 
105     7               1,2,3,4,5,6,7 
101     4               1,2,3,4 
102     2               1,2 
103     4               1,2,3,4 
104     1               1 
105     7               1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

The result will look like this:

```
item    row_value
101        1
101        2
101        3
101        4
102        1
102        2
103        1
103        2
103        3
103        4
104        1
105        1
105        2
105        3
105        4
105        5
105        6
105        7
```

Comment: Youe can use `tidyr::separate_rows(data, row_value_string, sep = ",")`

Comment: Thanks Kath. That's direct one.

Comment: Try `stack(setNames(strsplit(df1$row_value_string, ","), df1$Item))` in `base R`